# Commerce: Payment does not get completed

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am having trouble getting a payment completed (SaferPay, offsite gateway). After coming back from the payment provider I get redirected to the unchanged payment page again with the following error message: *Payment Error: ,* the error code (?) is 0.

I have found this in the logs:

```
$_GET=array (
'commerceTransactionId' => '87'
'commerceTransactionHash' => 'f4dcff157345d68b54934791fe7b0522'
)
$_POST=array (
'DATA' => '<IDP MSGTYPE="PayConfirm" TOKEN="(unused)" VTVERIFY="(obsolete)" KEYID="1-0" ID="Oh7p4zbhSnWOUAzjGE5bAS4rSnAb" ACCOUNTID="401860-17795278" PROVIDERID="1395" PROVIDERNAME="PayPal Saferpay Test" PAYMENTMETHOD="16" ORDERID="2435" AMOUNT="3071" CURRENCY="EUR" IP="84.141.245.197" IPCOUNTRY="DE" />'
'SIGNATURE' => '3eec17d64cd2f4e9e57402e3efb1d91d79af35cf462f1f971ad2aa79ceda5e6814d7fb4d82cf2bfe044c791cbc38ea3007598d4d0ac6ba16db08e1abb2dc0b61'
)
$_SESSION=array (
'1c4d338641dbdf309e6ed655daae834eYii.CWebUser.flash.error' => 'Payment Error: '
'1c4d338641dbdf309e6ed655daae834eYii.CWebUser.flashcounters' =>
array (
'error' => 0
)
)
```

The **QUERY_STRING** cuts after the transaction hash:

```
'commerceTransactionId=87&commerceTransactionHash=f4dcff157345d68b54934791fe7b0522'
```

Strangeley enough it is working locally, where the log says the following:

```
$_GET=array (
'commerceTransactionId' => '56'
'commerceTransactionHash' => '2db11e4c56020b3adad7565478f2bc56'
'DATA' => '<IDP MSGTYPE="PayConfirm" TOKEN="(unused)" VTVERIFY="(obsolete)" KEYID="1-0" ID="GCzE6MbphEYrSAUYhlA9bnvY6Y7b" ACCOUNTID="401860-17795278" PROVIDERID="1395" PROVIDERNAME="PayPal Saferpay Test" PAYMENTMETHOD="16" ORDERID="2435" AMOUNT="20430" CURRENCY="EUR" IP="84.141.245.197" IPCOUNTRY="DE" />'
'SIGNATURE' => '0378583461a09e40efe22a39cc5c7ca4c3bbe4e7f89c041154b00bcd1b65604309d219bad395ee2fefabc8726e9afd2364b769baa08ac927317698a9ab795e8b'
)
```

Remotely it lives on a sub domain. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which gateway driver are you using?

Comment: SaferPay by Six Payment Solutions. I had to make a plugin. I have just resolved the problem: a function collected the wrong data. Apparently the universe decided asking for help a required step to solving stuff on your own.

Comment: But a different problem arised: Now I have a Error Message: `DATA Atribute missing` although it is clearly there. If I catch the URL and use that a second time it works. What could that be?

Comment: Again, works locally.

Comment: Can you add an answer for the solution that worked for this question?  If you have a new question, you can post it separately.

Comment: Brad, just did.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the specific issue as such, but perhaps handy for future folks looking to debug issues in this area - you can dump the gateway request data with something like this in your business logic plugin:

(see hook docs here: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/hooks-reference#commerce_modifygatewayrequestdata)

```
    public function commerce_modifyGatewayRequestData($data,$type,$transaction)
{

        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("commerce_modifyGatewayRequestData"); 
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("data");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($data);
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("type");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($type);
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log("transaction");
        BusinessLogicPlugin::log($transaction);
 }
```

(assuming you have a `log` function in there that accepts strings and if not a string does a `var_dump`)

That at least gives you a full look at the data you're sending.

You can also modify the `$data` in there, and `return $data` at the end if you need to massage any of the data before submissin.  E.g. with `eWay` you should truncate some fields if they are too long or you will get errors...

E.g.

```
        if(isset($data['Customer']['Street1']))
        $data['Customer']['Street1'] = substr($data['Customer']['Street1'], 0, 49);

        ...etc

        return $data;
```

Similarly, after a transaction, you can log the response etc using this event: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_transactions.onsavetransaction

(See what you can log at https://craftcommerce.com/docs/transaction-model)

```
craft()->on('commerce_transactions.onSaveTransaction', function ($event){

    $transaction = $event->params['transaction'];
    BusinessLogicPlugin::log($transaction->response);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This is great! 
My issues have been resolved. I am adding my findings in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *Complete Function* of the SaferPay gateway had the wrong arguments which I didn’t catch first thus creating a malformed request, I guess. Fixing that solved the problem.

As for the second issue (`Missing DATA attribute`): turned out that I didn’t have CSRF protection enabled which I was sure that I had. But this Craft installation is from around 2014 and I only picked up working on it again this month. So I missed that also. Enabling it ([as suggested in the docs](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#csrf-protection-issues)) resolved that too so everything is working as expected now.

I have no idea about the inner workings of this so if anyone could enlighten me on that I would be very grateful. My knowledge of PHP is pretty much non existing and I am merely glueing stuff together and see what works.